# WP-CLI plugin delete command fails silently

Tags: plugins, wp-cli, windows

I have just started trying out WP-CLI and did a basic test of installing a plugin.

It installed fine, no issue. However, the `plugin delete` command fails silently, with no error messages and the plugin folder stays intact.

I am using a fresh WP and WP-CLI install on PHP 7

What may be of interest and a clue in the right direction to solving this, is that I cannot set the Wordpress folder (or any sub folder in it) to writable, instead the 'read only' checkbox is always checked, even after unchecking it and hitting apply.

If that is the issue, how do i fix the folder permissions on Windows to effectively be 777. Oh, and yes, I am using the admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re right and this could be a permissions related issue. First of all I wouldn’t recommend chanching all the WordPress directory permissions, only the wp-content directory and not to 777, instead permissions should be 755.

Probably you can’t change permissions on your FTP client because you’re not the owner of those files, more about that here [Understanding Linux File Permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).

You can try a couples of things:

1. If your hosting provider has cPanel or a similar panel you may find a file manager there that is just like an FTP client and maybe there you can change the permissions.
2. Or you could SSH into the server and set the permissions with this command: `chmod 755 wp-content`

More about changing file permissions here: [Changing File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: Sorry, this is local stuff, not on a remote server. I mentioned I'm on Windows, not Linux.